# Non defined array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, liquid

The code I'm writing is supossed to fetch a set of airports urls, and assign them to an array by code-url.

This is what I have so far:

```
<script>
    var airport = new Array();
    function CheckAirportCode(){
      {% for x in linklists['airports'].links %}
          var y = {{x.url}};
          y = y.match(/\/([A-Za-z0-9]{3})\-/);
          airport[y] = {{x.url}};
      {% endfor %}
    }

   $(document).ready(CheckAirportCode());
  </script>
```

but when I load the page and access the variable from the console browser, it says it is undefined. Any pointers ?

Comment: `airport` is not global, so you cannot access it from the browser console. If you need to do so, try removing the `var` keyword.

Comment: do you want a dictionary or set with a key value pair? If so use `var airport={};`

Comment: @depperm a key value pair.

Comment: `$(document).ready(CheckAirportCode());` should be `$(document).ready(CheckAirportCode);`

Comment: @epascarello You don't need to use the `()` for being a function?

Comment: @Onilol you pass in a function to `$()` - if you use `()` then you are passing in the function's *result*.  Might be better if you always use:  `$(document).ready(function() { ...code here... });` then there won't be any confusion now or in the future.

Comment: @Onilol: `()` is for *invoking* functions, not for *being* one. If you just want to pass it around as a value, only refer to the variable without an invocation.

Comment: Add an alert to your startup code to be sure it's running.  `airport` should be visible from the console given the code you've provided in the question.   So add this inside your `script`:   `$(function() { alert("startup"); });`.  If that doesn't appear, then there's something else wrong that's not in your question.

Comment: Thanks for everyone for the help. Removing var from the variable worked, not sure why tho.

Comment: Could someone make an official answer so the question doesn't remain unanswered ?